# Error with my Ajax post with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to post to a method using jQuery and Ajax. My Ajax code is as follows:

```
 var isMale = $(e.currentTarget).index() == 0 ? true : false;

 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/SetUpSession",
      data: { isMale: isMale },
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function() {
         // Go to next question
      }
 });
```

And here is my WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetUpSession(bool isMale)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) looking at the console, the method never get's hit. After I changed data to `"{}"` and removed the bool from the method signature the method then gets hit, so I'm assuming its something to do with the Ajax.data attribute I'm trying to pass.

Comment: Check if `Default.aspx` is present in the same directory, else try giving the correct relative URL.

Comment: @TaditKumarDash Eh? I don't really understand what you mean?

Comment: @HiTechMagic Apparently it is and the method gets hit, just not with those data attributes

Comment: the page where you have written this javaScript code should be present in the same folder where `Default.aspx` exists as per the your code. Do you understand now? If not present, you have to calculate the path and have to change the code, something like... `~/Default.aspx/SetUpSession`, if it is present in one level up parent folder.

Comment: What type/value is the variable isMale?

Comment: Try to pass string instead of bool.

Comment: @kostasch. You were correct. Please post it as an answer

Comment: @danrhul i have posted it.

Comment: @kostasch. And what you have posted is wrong. The method signature need not change. You should have changed it to: `"{ isMale: " + isMale.toString() + " }"`

Comment: So way you say that was right? Of course you have to pass string parameter and not bool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you need to modify :-

1) Make sure that this line is written in your web service page and should be **uncommented**.

**[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]**

2) Modify the "data" in the code as :-

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/SetUpSession",
      data: '{ isMale:"' + isMale + '"}',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function() {
         // Go to next question
      }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass string instead of bool

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetUpSession(string isMale)
{
// Do stuff
}
```

Alternative you can use pagemethods through script manager.

Comment: I can not understand people who have not have potential to explain why -1! The reason that they do such thing could help the poster and the readers but... they probably not want to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try following code:

```
var params = '{"isMale":"' + $(e.currentTarget).index() == 0 ? true : false + '"}';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/SetUpSession",
        data: params,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        responseType: "json",
        success: function (data) {}
   });

[WebMethod]
public static void SetUpSession(string isMale)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```